# Postgres jdbc driver problems with encoding

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, driver, postgresql-9.3

I use 9.3-1100-jdbc4 driver and I have UTF-8 as default encoding in Eclipse.
When I run my application I get stack trace but I can't read it

#### Error opening session.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ������������ "root" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)

I see smth like this. Is it possible to resolve this problem?

Comment: this message is from eclipse console?

Comment: @LadislavDANKO yes, this message from eclipse console in UTF-8

Comment: and what you get if you run your app as stand-alone aplication?

Comment: @LadislavDANKO yes, I just run test class with main method.

Comment: post your JDBC driver initialization code and info about enviroment (libs you use)

Answer (score 0):

Check what is your locale. Maybe it is not English?

See: [Java Internationalization: An Overview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/intlintro-142915.html)

PS While I'm from Poland I hate JDBC or other error messages translated into Polish. Especially for things that I have to find solution. Oracle adds error code ORA-[number] so it would be easier to find solution for such error but as we see on your message PostgreSQL do not use message codes independent from language.